# ggplot2 - facet_grid: How can I have varying range of values along the Y-axis but with the zero aligned?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider these dummy data

```
set.seed(12)
y = c(rnorm(120,0,1), rnorm(120,3,1), rnorm(120,0,120))
x = y + rnorm(120*3, 0,1)
d = data.frame(y=y,x=x,group=rep(1:3,each=120))
```

I would like to show the relationship between `x` and `y` within each `group` using `ggplot2`. I also would like to add a horizontal line at y=0.

I tried

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~group, nrow=1, scales="free_x") + geom_hline(yintercept = 0)
```

[image]

but we don't see much of the variance in `y` in the first two pannels. So I tried

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~group, scales="free", nrow=1) + geom_hline(yintercept = 0)
```

[image]

but now the horizontal lines aren't at the same level which bothers me.

How can I have varying range of values along the Y-axis but with the zero (or any other number) perfectly aligned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
egg::symmetrise_scale(last_plot(), 'y')
```

[image]

Comment: Great, a simple approach!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using the below code:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
    geom_point() +
    geom_blank(aes(y=-y)) + 
    facet_wrap(~group, scale="free", nrow=1) + 
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0)
```

[image]